# Cannot access empty property php class

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP, and some of its concept. I've following class for users:

```
    class Users
    {

        private $host   = DB_HOST;
        private $user   = DB_USERNAME;
        private $pass   = DB_PASSWORD;
        private $dbname = DB_NAME;

        private $conn;
        private $stmt;
        public  $error;

        function __construct()
        {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname.';charset=utf8';
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
            try {
                $this->conn = new PDO($dsn,$this->user,$this->pass,$options);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        private function mysql_execute_query($sql,$params)
        {
            $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $this->stmt->execute($params);
            return $this->$stmt;
        }

        public function find_user_by_provider_uid($provider,$provider_uid)
        {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE provider = :provider AND provider_uid = :provider_uid LIMIT 1';
            $params = array(
                ':provider'     => $provider,
                ':provider_uid' => $provider_uid
            );
            $result = $this->mysql_execute_query($sql,$params);
            return $result->fetch();
        }
}
```

First of all is there some tip that comes to mind for structuring this code better? or using more features of oop?

Second, it fails with following error:

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: stmt
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property

Both of this lines refer to return $this->$stmt; inside mysql_execute_query

My hunch is that it has something to do with it being private function. But I cannot tell.

Any ideas?

Comment: You used `$this->stmt` in one case and `$this->$stmt` in another. Don't you see the difference?

Comment: @zerkms I'm trully blind.

Comment: @salivan please inject a complete PDO instance in your class, instead of creating new DB connection every time you construct an instance of `Users`. Also, why are you using emulated prepares?

Comment: @tereško hi! Thanks to your recommendations on my previous question, I'm understanding more about oop, and moving in that direction. Slowly, but surely. I disabled emulated prepares, I didn't know PDO it is ON by default... PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, added this to options. Is it correct?

Comment: @salivan yes, that's correct. The emulation was turned on by default because pre-5.1 MySQL version did not support prepared statements. You could say it was a very short-sighed patch for a temporary problem. PHP core team has this nasty fetish for backwards compatibility =/ Also on a different note, when you pass parameters through `execute()` they all are bound as `PDO::PARAM_STR`. You might want to look int PDO's `bintParam()` methods, since some of your values looks kinda like integers and should be bound as such.

Comment: @tereško well sometimes its good this fetish :) I'm not so well versed in php to have any opinion though... About your other first comment, yes, I see how that can be a problem. But what do you mean by injecting it directly? You mean without constructor?

Comment: No, I mean in the constructor. Basically you do `$user = new Users(new PDO('mysql:...', $user, $pass));` or better: `$pdo = new PDO(...); $users = new Users($pdo); $docs = new Documents($pdo); .. etc`. This way you can share the same connection instance between multiple object. When you pass an object as parameter, it does **not** get copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the error:

```
return $this->$stmt;
```

But should be:

```
return $this->stmt;
```

Comment: I repeat myself, I'm blind :|